# How to stop activity indicator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiactivityindicatorview

How to stop UIActivityIndicatorView? This code doesn't work.

BubbleTableViewCell.h:

```
@interface BubbleTableViewCell : UITableViewCell {

    UIActivityIndicatorView *activity;
}
```

BubbleTableViewCell.m:

```
- (void)setActivity:(BOOL)value {

    if (value) {
        activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
        activity.center = CGPointMake(15, 15);
        [activity startAnimating];
        [self.contentView addSubview:activity];
    }
    else {
        [activity stopAnimating];
        [activity removeFromSuperview];
        [activity release];
    }
}
```

Comment: this code seems perfect to me.

Comment: And for me too! But it doesn't work!

Comment: How are you getting the reference to the UITableViewCell, to call the method -(void)setActivity:(BOOL)value; ????

Answer (score 0):

I can only suppose where and why you need the activity indicator but if you need it whilst data is loading you may do so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
UITableViewCell * cell;
MyCustomCell * myCell = [TableViewCellsFactory loadCellFromNibWithName:@"myCell" identifier:@"myCell" tableView:aTableView owner:self];
if(dataIsLoading) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"loadingCell"] autorelease];
    UIActivityIndicatorView * activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    [activityIndicator setFrame:CGRectMake(140, 40, 40,  40)];
    [cell addSubview:activityIndicator];
}
else {
    //here you customize myCell
    cell = myCell;
}
return cell;
```

This works perfect for me....

Answer (score 0):

Just debug the status of the value in both case. I think BOOL value once set to true is not changing to false to execute else part.

Answer (score 0):

Did you set the activity twice?
One possible is that you lose your reference if you call this function twice with same BOOL value

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that you want to show the activity indicator in UITableViewCell while some data (like image) is getting downloaded, and once it gets downloaded then you want to stop the indicator. One approach to do this in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method is:

- Check if the data which needs to be downloaded (ex: image) is available or not.

  If the data is available call the method `setActivity:` with `NO` in the parameter.

  But if the data is not available, then call the method `setActivity:` with `YES` in the parameter, and start downloading the corresponding data.

  Once the data is downloaded, reload the particular cell using

  ```
  - (void)reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:(NSArray *)indexPaths withRowAnimation:(UITableViewRowAnimation)animation
  ```

  Now when the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is called, your data for the row will be downloaded and the method `setActivity:` will be called with  `NO` in the parameter, which will hide the indicator (if any).

With this approach you have to modify the function a little bit to:

```
- (void)setActivity:(BOOL)value 
{
  if (value)
  {
    activity = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc]initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
    activity.center = CGPointMake(15, 15);
    [activity startAnimating];
    [self.contentView addSubview:activity];
  }
  else
  {
    if(activity)
    {
      [activity stopAnimating];
      [activity removeFromSuperview];
      [activity release];
    }
  }
}
```